# represent half hour time increment in javascript if else if

Tags: javascript, xml, time

I have built a simple stock feed that uses xml and javascript. i aded in a conditional based on time so before the market is open it shows the previous close, while its open it shows the ask price, when it is closed, it shows the last price. It works, but only if the time interval is a whole number. i need my time intervals to be 9:30 to 4:30 (16:30) but when I try to augment the time to the half hour it errors.

Here is my code, how do i display the time intervals as 9:30 and 16:30?

```
var time = new Date().getHours();
var data;
if (time < 10) {
    data = x[0].getElementsByTagName("PREVIOUSCLOSE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;}

else if (time < 16) {
    data = x[0].getElementsByTagName("ASK")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;}
else {data = x[0].getElementsByTagName("LASTPRICE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use minutes together with hours

```
var date  = new Date();
var hours = date.getHours();
var mins  = date.getMinutes();
var data;

if (hours < 9 || ( hours < 10 && minutes < 30  ) ) {

    data = x[0].getElementsByTagName("PREVIOUSCLOSE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

} else if (hours < 16 || ( hours < 17 && minutes < 30)) {

    data = x[0].getElementsByTagName("ASK")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

} else {

    data = x[0].getElementsByTagName("LASTPRICE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

}
```

Comment: Better use `hours == 9` and `hours == 16` instead of `hours < 10` and `hours < 17`